# Rails Devise redirects to sign in upon registration attempt

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

Rails is now redirecting me to log in after I try to register a new user, you just get the error 'You need to sign in or sign up before continuing.' New users do not get saved into the database.

My first thought was that I was redirecting to a page that required authentication, but shouldn't it still create a new user? I have checked all my controllers and the only ones requiring authentication have it on create, update, and destroy. I have `before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]` on two controllers. This leads me to my next point, which is that authentication shouldn't matter because I made a registrations controller that redirects to the home page after signup (which is an index that doesn't require authentication).

Registrations Controller:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  protected

  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    root_path
  end
end
```

My routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root to: "home#index"
  devise_for :users, path: '', path_names: { sign_in: 'login', sign_out: 'logout', sign_up: 'register' }, 
    controllers: { registrations: "registrations" }

  resources :blogs do
    member do
      put 'like', to: 'blogs#upvote'
      put 'dislike', to: 'blogs#downvote'
    end
    resources :comments do
      member do
        put 'like', to: 'comments#upvote'
        put 'dislike', to: 'comments#downvote'
      end
    end
  end

  get 'tags/:tag', to: 'tags#show', as: :tag

  match '/users', to: 'users#index', via: 'get'
  match '/users/:id', to: 'users#show', via: 'get'

  #devise_for :users, :path_prefix => 'd'
  resources :users, :only =>[:show]
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

I have all the whitelisted stuff in a concern:

```
module DeviseWhitelist 
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?
  end

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:username])
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [:username, :picture, :picture_cache, :remove_picture])
  end
end
```

My Application Controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  include DeviseWhitelist
  include DefaultPageContent
end
```

And my User model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  mount_uploader :picture, PictureUploader
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  validates_presence_of :username
  validates_presence_of :picture
  validates_integrity_of :picture
  validates_processing_of :picture

  has_many :blogs
  has_many :comments
  has_many :logs
  acts_as_voter

  private
    def picture_size_validation
      errors[:picture] << "should be less than 500KB" if picture.size > 0.5.megabytes
    end
end
```

And my Register form:

```
<h2>Sign up</h2>

<%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), html: { method: :put, multipart: true }) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true %><br />
    <%= f.input :password, required: true, hint: ("#{@minimum_password_length} characters minimum" if @minimum_password_length) %>
    <%= f.input :password_confirmation, required: true %>
    <%= f.label :username %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :username %><br />

    <%= f.label :picture do %>
    <%= f.file_field :picture %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :picture_cache %>
    <% end %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit, "Register" %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

User Controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @page_title = "Users"
    @users = User.all
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @page_title = @user.username
    @blogs = @user.blogs
    @articles = @user.articles
    @logs = @user.logs
    @almost_everything = (@blogs + @articles).sort{|b,a| a.updated_at <=> b.updated_at }
    @everything = (@almost_everything + @logs).sort{|b,a| a.updated_at <=> b.updated_at }
  end

end
```

Here is my console results from trying to register a new user:

```
Started PUT "/" for 70.59.200.105 at 2017-05-13 16:12:06 +0000
Cannot render console from 70.59.200.105! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Processing by RegistrationsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"uWuUhNMZzypqEDooxadjUf0/pIAXOJdmBuaynRSNvuqCSsx40FBPCOxt0howIiX9jLChlDsCmgmAtmGaqIMOzA==", "user"=>{"email"=>"dave@example.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "username"=>"dave", "picture"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f38e4a702a0 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20170513-3045-wtfbgh.jpg>, @original_filename="42_ac79fe347c2c43c183e6d915b4922091.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"user[picture]\"; filename=\"42_ac79fe347c2c43c183e6d915b4922091.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">, "picture_cache"=>""}, "commit"=>"Register"}
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

Started GET "/login" for 70.59.200.105 at 2017-05-13 16:12:06 +0000
Cannot render console from 70.59.200.105! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
  Rendering devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered devise/shared/_links.html.erb (2.1ms)
  Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (19.8ms)
  Rendered shared/_nav.html.erb (5.5ms)
  Rendered shared/_footer.html.erb (8.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 129ms (Views: 126.7ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

I feel like I've checked every file in my project. Why would this be happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by changing the method to post in my new registration view, but I also had to add this to my registrations controller:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  protected

  wrap_parameters :user, include: [:username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :picture]

  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    root_path
  end
end
```

View:

```
<%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), html: { method: :post, multipart: true }) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>
```

Answer (score 1):

> I have checked all my controllers and the only ones requiring
>   authentication have it on create, update, and destroy.

The reason you are being redirected is because you have authentication for the create action. Add create to this code block and it should work:

```
before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show, :create]
```

Alternatively, you can use only instead of except:

```
before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:update, :destroy]
```

Also, keep in mind, currently you don't have to be logged in to edit anything because you are not requiring authentication on the edit action.

Comment: That's for creating a new blog post, though. The other controller I have that on is articles, so only registered users can create new content. Just to test it, I went ahead and added it, but I have the same error.

Comment: Edited my question. I'm only using the user controller for index and show functions.

Comment: What do you see in the console after you redirect?

Comment: I've added the console results.